# Crear y ejecutar consultas dinámicas en PHP con datos recibidos vía jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que maneja una cantidad considerable de datos ubicados en varias (bastantes) tablas de una base de datos MySQL.

La aplicación presenta un formulario con varias fuentes de entrada: inputs, selects, etc. Al presionar un botón se lanza código jQuery que determina la acción a ejecutar según los elementos que tienen datos.

El código jQuery me construye datos como estos más o menos:

```
var data = {
                'action': 'insert', 
                'id_liturgia':idLiturgia, 
                'id_himno':idHimno,  
                'tabla':'liturgia_horas_himnos_join'
            };
```

Los datos almacenados en `data` son enviados al servidor y éste determina el tipo de acción contenido en `action` para actuar en consecuencia.

Lo que yo quiero es que, en PHP, cuando `action` contenga `insert` construir una consulta dinámica basada en los otros elementos que vienen en `data`. La consulta tomará el nombre de la tabla de `data` también.

Para este caso, la consulta sería algo así:

```
INSERT INTO 
liturgia_horas_himnos_join  
(id_liturgia, id_himno) 
VALUES (:id_liturgia, : id_himno);
```

El problema es que lo que recibo en data puede ser diferente. Por ejemplo, aquí hay más de una columna a insertar. En `data` habrá siempre al principio la `action` a ejecutar y al final el nombre de la tabla:

```
var data = {
                'action': 'insert', 
                'id_liturgia':idLiturgia, 
                'id_antifona':idAntifona,  
                'id_tema':idTema,  
                'id_epigrafe':idEpigrafe,  
                'id_salmo':idSalmo,  
                'tabla':'liturgia_horas_salmos_grupos'
            };
```

**¿Cómo podría construir una consulta de forma dinámica, que use marcadores de nombre, tomando en cuenta que siempre la variable `data` traerá en el primer elemento la acción y en el último el nombre de la tabla?**

Como nota aclaratoria, todos los demás elementos son datos a insertar y por lógica les he dado como llave el mismo nombre de columna que tienen en la base de datos, de esa forma será más fácil crear una consulta preparada usando marcadores de nombre, como muestra el ejemplo de más arriba..

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar una *librería* [`CRUD`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) *(**C**reate, **R**ead, **U**pdate, **D**elete)* para Crear, Leer, Actualizar y Borrar el cual se usa para referirse a las funciones básicas en bases de datos.

Te dejo unas librerías **CRUD** y **DB**:

Class **CRUD**:

```html
<?php
/**
* CRUD - Operations
*
* by Daniel Arroyo Villora <https://danielarroyo.es> aka aldanux <https://github.com/aldanux>
*/

class Crud
{
  private $_db = null;

  public function __construct( $db ) {

    $this->_db = $db;
  }

  public function customSql( string $sql, array $array = [] ) {

    return $this->exec( $sql, $array );
  }

  public function fetchOneFrom( string $table, array $binds = [], array $fields = [], array $order_by = [] ) {

    if ( !empty( $table ) ) {

      $sql = "SELECT ";

      if ( empty( $fields ) ) {

        $sql .= " * ";
      }
      else {

        $sql .= implode( ", ", $fields );
      }

      $sql .= " FROM {$table} ";

      if ( !empty( $binds ) ) {

        $binds_vals = [];

        $key_binds = array_keys( $binds );

        foreach ( $key_binds as $key_bind ) {

            $binds_vals[] = "{$key_bind} = :{$key_bind}";
        }

        $sql .= " WHERE ".implode( " AND ", $binds_vals );      
      }
      else {

        $sql .= " WHERE 1 ";
      }

      if ( !empty( $order_by ) ) {

        $sort_vals = [];

        foreach ( $order_by as $key => $value ) {

          $sort_vals[] = "{$key} {$value}";
        }

        $sql .= " ORDER BY ".implode( ", ", $sort_vals );
      }

      $sql .= " LIMIT 1;";

      return $this->execRow( $sql, $binds );
    }

    return false;
  }

  public function fetchAllFrom( string $table, array $binds = [], array $fields = [], array $order_by = [] ) {

    if ( !empty( $table ) ) {

    $sql = "SELECT ";

      if ( empty( $fields ) ) {

        $sql .= " * ";
      }
      else {

        $sql .= implode( ", ", $fields );
      }

      $sql .= " FROM {$table} ";

      if ( !empty( $binds ) ) {

          $binds_vals = [];

          $key_binds = array_keys( $binds );

          foreach ( $key_binds as $key_bind ) {

            $binds_vals[] = "{$key_bind} = :{$key_bind}";
          }

          $sql .= " WHERE ".implode( " AND ", $binds_vals );
      }
      else {

        $sql .= " WHERE 1 ";
      }

      if ( !empty( $order_by ) ) {

        $sort_vals = [];

        foreach ( $order_by as $key => $value ) {

          $sort_vals[] = "{$key} {$value}";
        }

        $sql .= " ORDER BY ".implode( ", ", $sort_vals );
      }

      $sql .= ";";

      return $this->execQuery( $sql, $binds );
    }

    return false;
  }

  public function insert( string $table, array $binds = [] ) {

    if ( !empty( $table ) ) {

      if ( !empty( $binds ) ) {

        $fields      = array_keys( $binds );
        $fields_vals = [ implode( ',', $fields ), ':'.implode( ',:', $fields ) ];
        $sql         = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields_vals[ 0 ]}) VALUES ({$fields_vals[ 1 ]});";
      }
      else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} () VALUES ()";
      }

      return $this->execQuery( $sql, $binds );
    }

    return false;
  }

  public function update( string $table, array $binds = [], array $pks = [] ) {

    if ( !empty( $table ) && !empty( $binds ) ) {

      $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";

      $binds_sets = [];
      $binds_vals = [];

      $no_pks_keys = array_values( array_diff( array_keys( $binds ), $pks ) );
      $pks_keys    = array_diff( array_keys( $binds ), array_values( $no_pks_keys ) );

    if ( !empty( $pks ) ) {

      foreach ( $pks as $pks_val ) {

        foreach ( $binds as $bind_key => $bind_val ) {

          $check_increment_decrement_key = strpos( $bind_val, $bind_key ) > -1;

          if ( $check_increment_decrement_key && \DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d G:i:s', $bind_val ) === false ) {

            list( $key, $operator, $value ) = explode( ' ', $bind_val );

            $binds_sets[] = "{$bind_key} = {$key} {$operator} {$value}";
            unset( $binds[ $bind_key ] );
          }
          else {

            if ( $bind_key !== $pks_val && !in_array( $bind_key, $pks_keys ) ) {

              $binds_sets[] = "{$bind_key} = :{$bind_key}";
            }
          }

          if ( $bind_key === $pks_val ) {

            $binds_vals[] = "{$bind_key} = :{$bind_key}";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {

      foreach ( $binds as $bind_key => $bind_val ) {

        $check_increment_decrement_key = strpos( $bind_val, $bind_key ) > -1;

        if ( $check_increment_decrement_key && \DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d G:i:s', $bind_val ) === false ) {

          list( $key, $operator, $value ) = explode( ' ', $bind_val );

          $binds_sets[] = "{$bind_key} = {$key} {$operator} {$value}";
          unset( $binds[ $bind_key ] );
          }
          else {

            $binds_sets[] = "{$bind_key} = :{$bind_key}";
          }
        }
      }

      $binds_sets = array_unique( $binds_sets );

      $sql .= implode( ", ", $binds_sets );

      if ( !empty( $pks ) ) {

        $sql .= " WHERE ".implode( " AND ", $binds_vals );
      }

      $sql .= ";";

      return $this->execQuery( $sql, $binds );
    }

    return false;
  }

  private function execQuery( string $sql, array $array = [] ) {

    return $this->_db->query( $sql, $array );
  }

  private function execRow( string $sql, array $array = [] ) {

    return $this->_db->row( $sql, $array );
  }
}
```

Class **DB**:

```html
<?php
/**
* DataBase - Configuration
*
* by Daniel Arroyo Villora <https://danielarroyo.es> aka aldanux <https://github.com/aldanux>
*/
use PDO;

class DB
{
  private $_pdo;

  private $_query;

  private $_is_db_connected = false; 

  private $_parameters;

  public function __construct() {

    $this->_connect();
    $this->_parameters = [];
  }

  public function closeConnection() {

    $this->_pdo = null;
  }

  // Add the parameter to the parameter array
  public function bind( $parameters, $value ): void {

    $this->_parameters[ sizeof( $this->_parameters ) ] = [ ':'.$parameters, $value ];
  }

  // Add the parameter to the parameter array
  public function bindMore( array $parameters_array ): void {

    if ( empty( $this->_parameters ) && is_array( $parameters_array ) ) {

      $columns = array_keys( $parameters_array );

      foreach ( $columns as $i => &$column ) {

          $this->bind( $column, $parameters_array[ $column ] );
      }
    }
  }

  /*
  *  If the SQL query  contains a SELECT or SHOW statement it returns an array containing all of the result set row
  *  If the SQL statement is a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement it returns the number of affected rows
  * 
  */
  public function query( string $query, array $parameters = [], int $fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) {

    $result       = null;
    $query        = trim( str_replace( "\r", " ", $query ) );
    $rawStatement = explode( " ", preg_replace( "/\s+|\t+|\n+/", " ", $query ) );

    $statement = strtolower( $rawStatement[ 0 ] );

    $this->_init( $query, $parameters );

    if ( $statement === 'select' || $statement === 'show' ) {

      $result = $this->_query->fetchAll( $fetchmode );
    }
    else if ( $statement === 'insert' || $statement === 'update' || $statement === 'delete' ) {

      $result = $this->_query->rowCount();
    }

    $this->_query->closeCursor();

    return $result;
  }

  // Returns an array which represents a column from the result set
  public function column( string $query, array $parameters = [] ): array {

    $this->_init( $query, $parameters );
    $Columns = $this->_query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_NUM );
    $this->_query->closeCursor();

    $column = [];

    foreach ( $Columns as $cells ) {

      $column[] = $cells[ 0 ];
    }

    return $column;
  }

  // Returns an array which represents a row from the result set
  public function row( string $query, array $parameters = [], int $fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) {

    $this->_init( $query, $parameters );
    $result = $this->_query->fetch( $fetchmode );
    $this->_query->closeCursor();

    return $result;
  }

  // Returns the value of one single field/column
  public function single( string $query, array $parameters = [] ) {

    $this->_init( $query, $parameters );
    $result = $this->_query->fetchColumn();
    $this->_query->closeCursor();

    return $result;
  }

  public function lastInsertId() {

    return $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
  }

  public function beginTransaction() {

    return $this->_pdo->beginTransaction();
  }

  public function executeTransaction() {

    return $this->_pdo->commit();
  }

  public function rollBack() {

    return $this->_pdo->rollBack();
  }

  public function rowCount() {

    return $this->_query->rowCount();
  }

  private function _connect() {

    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
    ];

    try {

      $this->_pdo        = new PDO( DSN, USER, PW, $opt );
      $this->_is_db_connected = true;
    }
    catch ( PDOException $e ) {

      // Handle error properly
    }
  }

  // Every method which needs to execute a SQL query uses this method
  private function _init( string $query, array $parameters = [] ): void {

    if ( !$this->_is_db_connected ) {
      $this->_connect();
    }

    try {

      $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare( $query );

      $this->bindMore( $parameters );

      if ( !empty( $this->_parameters ) ) {

        foreach ( $this->_parameters as $key => $value ) {

          if ( is_int( $value[ 1 ] ) ) {
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
          }
          else if ( is_bool( $value[ 1 ] ) ) {
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
          }
          else if ( is_null( $value[ 1 ] ) ) {
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
          }
          else {
            $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
          }

          // Add type when binding the values to the column
          $this->_query->bindValue( $value[ 0 ], $value[ 1 ], $type );
        }
      }

      $this->_query->execute();
    }
    catch ( PDOException $e ) {
      // Handle error properly
    }

    $this->_parameters = [];
  }
}
```

Unos ejemplo de uso:

```
// Iniciar
$db   = new DB();
$crud = new Crud( $db );

// INSERT (Create) => Parámetros: $table (obligatorio), $binds (opcional)
$crud->insert( 'tu_tabla', [ 'columna1' => $columna1, 'columna2' => $columna2 ] );

// Fetch One (Read) => Parámetros: $tabla (obligatorio), $binds (opcional = WHERE 1), $fields (opcional = '*'), $order_by (opcional) // 'LIMIT 1'
$crud->fetchOneFrom( 'tu_tabla', [ 'where1' => $where1, 'where2' => $where2 ], ['field1' => $field1 ], ['orderby1'] => 'DESC' );

// Fetch All (Read) => Parámetros: $tabla (obligatorio), $binds (opcional = WHERE 1), $fields (opcional = '*'), $order_by (opcional)
$crud->fetchAllFrom( 'tu_tabla', [ 'where1' => $where1, 'where2' => $where2 ], ['field1' => $field1 ], ['orderby1'] => 'DESC' );

// UPDATE (Update) => Parámetros: $tabla (obligatorio), $binds (obligatorio), $pks (opcional)
// se puede usar ' + n' y ' - n' para incrementar o decrementar 
$crud->update( 'tu_tabla', [ 'id1' => $id1, 'set2' => 'set2 + 1' ], ['id1'] );

// Delete (Delete) => No lo uso nunca :)
```

Comment: Interesante lo de la librería CRUD. Aunque no queda del todo claro, por lo que veo maneja las consultas preparadas ¿no?. En cuanto a la conexión a la BD me reservaré el derecho de usar [mi propia clase](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO).

Comment: @A.Cedano - La única razón por dejarte las dos librerías era porque tenia demasiado dependencias para dejarte solo la parte donde se construye el `INSERT`... Y si... maneja las consultas preparadas... para cualquier duda o posibles mejoras me avisas... saludos

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo los nombres 'id_liturgia 'id_tema' son los nombres que irian en el insert ('id_liturgia 'id_tema')  y vos no lo estas pasando como parámetro, sino como nombre de la variable, y eso no lo podrias saber.
Por lo que veo, vos con un solo codigo, que supongo que es .php, queres resolver todas las consultas a la BD, es complejo lo que queres hacer. Se me ocurre hacer algo asi:

```html
var data = {
                'action': 'insert', 
                campos:id_liturgia&id_antifona&id_tema
                valores:vid_liturgia&vid_antifona&vid_tema           
                'tabla':'liturgia_horas_salmos_grupos'
            };
            
 En la api que recibe el data:
$arraycampos=split("&", $_POST["campos"]);
$arrayvalores=split("&", $_POST["campos"]);
```

La idea es que con estos dos array hagas un if else, segun la accion y los recorras y crees la consulta insert o update segun corresponda.
Si no sabes como recorrer los array y crear las consultas .me decis, pero no es complicado, ojalá te sea útil. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer un ciclo "for", para solo sacar los campos que quieres insertar, es decir, armar una cadena de texto con ellos. Teniendo en cuenta que no tomarias en cuenta, el primer elemento del array, y tampoco el ultimo.

```
$total_elementos_array = sizeof($_POST);
$indice_ultimo_elemento = $total_elementos_array -1;
$tabla = $_POST[ indice_ultimo_elemento ];
$cadena_campos = "";
$cadena_valores = "";
$limite_para_agregar_separador = $indice_ultimo_elemento -1;
$keys_array = array_keys($_POST) ;//Estos serian los nombres de los campos de la DB

for($i= 1; $i < ( $total_elementos_array - 1 ); $i++)//Empezar de uno, para no tomar en cuenta "action"
{
    $separador = ",";//Separador de los campos

    if( $i != $indice_ultimo_elemento )
    {
        $campo_DB = $keys_array[ $i ];//Campo de la DB a insertar
        $valor_campo = $_POST[ $i ];//Valor a insertar en la DB
        if( $i == $limite_para_agregar_separador)
        {
            $separador = "";
        }
        $cadena_campos .= $campo_DB.$separador;
        $cadena_valores .= $valor_campo.$separador;
    }
}


//Ahora solo resta armar la consulta
$consulta = "INSERT INTO ".$tabla." ( ".$cadena_campos." ) VALUES ( ".$cadena_valores." )";
```

No es la solución concreta, pero espero sirva la ayuda. La clave es sacar los keys del array que recibe el servidor, y separar sus respectivos values.